# Working with byte array I get an "invalid conversion from char* to byte"

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am reading and writing to an RFID tag using MFRC522.h
I can currently read the UID of a card and dump it to "UIDChar"
The UID of a card typically is 8 characters.

```
UID Example:  467EE9A9
```

I can use the mfrc522.MIFARE_SetUid function to write this UID to a new card.  In order to do this I have to set the newUID to:

```
0x46,0x7E,0xE9,0xA9f
```

I have written this into my code. 
What I am wanting to do is convert the UID string into a byte array so that I can use that in place of my manually written 0x46,0x7E,0xE9,0xA9.

I use the convert function to convert the UID into that format. 
It can that be displayed with "buf".

```
Serial.println(buf);
```

Now my problem.  If I replace the

```
byte newUid[] = {0x46,0x7E,0xE9,0xA9f};
```

with

```
byte newUid[] = {buf};
```

I get the error
invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'byte {aka unsigned char}'

How can I set my "newUid" as "buf"?

```
#define SS_PIN 0  //D2
#define RST_PIN 2 //D1

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>


/* For RFID */
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
char buf[40]; // For string to byte array convertor

void convert(char *s)
{
 int i, j, k;
 buf[0] = 0x0;

 for (j = 0, i = 0, k = 0; j < strlen(s); j++)
 {

   if (i++ == 0) {
     buf[k++] = '0';
     buf[k++] = 'x';
   }

   buf[k++] = s[j];

   if (i == 2) {
     if(j != strlen(s) -1)  buf[k++] = ',';
     i = 0;
   }
 }

buf[k] = 0x0;

}

void clone() {

 /* RFID Read */
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(" UID tag :");

  //  Very basic UID dump
  unsigned int hex_num;
  hex_num =  mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0] << 24;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[1] << 16;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[2] <<  8;
  hex_num += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[3];

  // Get UID
  int  NFC_id = (int)hex_num;
  Serial.print(NFC_id, HEX);

  // Convert UID to string using an int and a base (hexadecimal)
  String stringUID =  String(NFC_id, HEX);
  char UIDChar[10];
  stringUID.toCharArray(UIDChar,10);

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println();


  // Convert to uppercase
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(UIDChar); i++ )
  {
    if ( UIDChar[i] == NULL ) break;
    UIDChar[i] = toupper(UIDChar[i]);
  }

  //Serial.print( &UIDChar[0] );
  Serial.println();
  convert(UIDChar);
  Serial.println(buf);

   /* RFID Write */

   // Set new UID
   //  Change your UID hex string to 4 byte array

   // I get error if I use byte newUid[] = {buf};
 /*  ERROR HERE */
  byte newUid[] = {0x46,0x7E,0xE9,0xA9};
  if ( mfrc522.MIFARE_SetUid(newUid, (byte)4, true) ) {
    Serial.println( "Wrote new UID to card." );
  }

  // Halt PICC and re-select it so DumpToSerial doesn't get confused
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {
    return;
  }

  // Dump the new memory contents
  Serial.println( "New UID and contents:" );
  mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin ( 115200 );

  /* RFID */
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522

  clone();

}

void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
byte newUid[] = {buf};
```

you are trying to initialise `newUid` with a single element (there's only one item inside your `{}`), and that element is `buf`, which is a `char*` (or a `char[]`). That's why you get the error - you are trying to assign an array with one `char*` to a variable whose elements are `byte`s.

Without reading your full code in detail, I don't know why you are trying to do this assignment, rather than just use your `buf` array as it is. But to fix the problem, you probably just want to use

```
byte* newUid = buf;
```

Comment: Because it's for Arduino, the library is located at https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522Extended.cpp

I get 'initializer fails to determine size of "newUid"' when I use byte newUid[] = buf;

I'll dig into it some more.

Comment: In that case try just `byte* newUid = buf;`. Since it's not declaring it as an array, it doesn't need to know the size.